# Make all components fit in one page in Svelte

Tags: html, css, flexbox, svelte

Hello !

I need help about some css. (I think)

I have a  svelte project where I need just to display 7 "block" which all fit in one page.

The actual code is this for the App.svelte :

```
<script>
    import Podcast from "./components/Podcast.svelte";
</script>

<style>

    body
    {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }

</style>
<body>
    <Podcast color={"red"} title={"red"}/>
    <Podcast color={"green"} title={"green"}/>
    <Podcast color={"blue"} title={"blue"}/>
    <Podcast color={"purple"} title={"purple"}/>
    <Podcast color={"yellow"} title={"yellow"}/>
    <Podcast color={"brown"} title={"brown"}/>
    <Podcast color={"orange"} title={"orange"}/>
</body>
```

and this for the component :

```
<script>
    export let title;
    export let color;
</script>

<style>
    body
    {
        width: auto; 
        height: 9em;
    }

    .title
    {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    .centerTitle
    {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-items: center;
    }

</style>

<body style="background-color: {color}">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="centerTitle">
            The title is : <b>{title}</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMyrG.png)

there is still a white border at bottom !

and btw if you know how i could center vertically / horizontally the text i would be glad to know too !

Answer (score 0):

Avoid creating `body` tags inside the svelte component. Your svelte app mounts to the `body` of the `index.html` of your project. Also, if you take a look at the default `global.css` you will find the body to have padding you can remove it.

I have a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d28b89d43b18484a8b60b8a9e0e57add?version=3.38.2) you can check it out this can help you, I have used `display:grid` but also included a `flex` example

Comment: Okay but I can't really understand how this will make all in one page ?

Comment: I tried your solution but I have a problem using flex: the variable passed is like stick to the ":" like this : ```The title is :red``` but the code is : ```The title is :<b> {title} </b>``` why that ?

Comment: You can strip out the spaces at `The title is:<b>{title}</b>` if you want it this way.